How to fix Razor Pages CRUD Scaffolding Error
I'm running VS 2022, and have a Razor Pages site created. I tried to scaffold Razor CRUD pages and received the following error:

and this is what outputted:

Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
Running the generator 'razorpage'...
Minimal hosting scenario!
Exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' was thrown.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.b__6_0()
at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)

I had cleared the Nuget Package cache, updated all packages and still receive the error message.
The following are the nuget package versions I have in the csproj file:
      <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RootNamespace>Van_Authentication</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration" Version="8.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="8.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

Searching online, I cannot find any other solutions. I was able to scaffold pages earlier, so not sure what happened. I attempted to restore the project to an earlier GIT commit but it's corrupted and won't revert.
How do I fix the scaffolding error?

Hi @kyros, i did not meet such issue when scaffold the razor pages with your nuget packages. Have your application build successfully without any exception or error? Please run your application and check if any problems.

BTW, did you migrate your project from other version to .NET 8?

Hi Rena, yes my application builds successfully without any errors, I do get a few nullable warnings though. I started the project on .NET 8. I was able to successfully scaffold CRUD pages before. Unfortunately I did not work on this project for several weeks so it is a little difficult to pin point when this issue started.

I was able to solve the issue. Prior to scaffolding Razor CRUD pages, I changed the folder structure to a bunch of razor pages. Not all of the namespaces were changed to reflect the new folder structure.
I modified all the namespaces to the new folder structure and was able to scaffold the razor CRUD pages successfully!
Thanks for all the help.

Install this package then try again.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design


I uninstalled and reinstalled Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design. Still getting the same error
